# Custom error message for Laravel validation rule: Dimensions

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, validationerror

I'm trying to validate an image upload that looks like the following:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'admin_image'=> 'nullable|image|dimensions:min_width=600,min_height=600',
]);
```

when the selected image too small then laravel shows error:

```
The Admin Image has invalid image dimensiona
```

I think that message is not saying specifically that in which dimension the image small, eg: width or height.

I'm expecting error message like:
`The Admin Image width cannot be less than 600px` and
`The Admin Image height cannot be less than 600px`

here 'Admin image' is the attribute name & '600' is the value I given in rules

So, I wanted to make a custom error message for `min_width` and `max_width`in `custom` messages array on validation.php, that look like the following:

```
'admin_image' => [
            'dimensions.min_width' => 'The :attribute dimension (width) cannot be less than :min_width px',
            'dimensions.min_height' => 'The :attribute dimension (height) cannot be less than :min_height px',
        ],
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work & Laravel continues to show the default message.

Please understand that

## I need 2 separate error message for `dimensions:min_width=600` & `dimensions:min_height=600`

like I tried in the custom error messages array.

I know this is very simple but I'm doing something wrong.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You can use the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226644/fields-validation-default-message-change-in-laravel-5-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the custom error message in `validation.php` as below:

```
'admin_image' => [
    'dimensions' => [
        'min_width' => 'The :attribute dimension (width) cannot be less than :min_width px'
    ]
 ]
```