# Fields validation default message change in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am using this code for validating a field.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'recovery_code' => 'required|exists:users,email_recovery_code',
    'new_password'=>'required',
    'confirm_password'=>'required|same:new_password',
    ]);
```

and when I enter wrong recovery code i get response

```
"The selected recovery code is invalid"
```

but in place of that I want my custom message. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its simple, Just do as like this:

```
$messages = [
        'exists' => 'Your custom message',
    ];
    $this->validate($request, [
    'recovery_code' => 'required|exists:users,email_recovery_code',
    'new_password'=>'required',
    'confirm_password'=>'required|same:new_password',
    ],$messages);
```

You can set multiple checks on same field in laravel. Just pass them in an array with different key. e.g: exists, required, etc.

Hope it helps you.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-error-messages):

> If needed, you may use custom error messages for validation instead of the defaults. There are several ways to specify custom messages. First, you may pass the custom messages as the third argument to the `Validator::make` method:

```
$messages = [
    'recovery_code' => 'Your custom error message',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

> Sometimes you may wish to specify a custom error messages only for a specific field. You may do so using "dot" notation. Specify the attribute's name first, followed by the rule:

```
$messages = [
    'recovery_code. required' => 'Your custom error message',
];
```

Answer (score 2):

define a $messages array and pass it to `validate()` method

```
$messages = [
'recovery_code.exists' => 'custom error message',
```

];

```
$this->validate($request, $rules,$messages);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I think to change default messages.

**1.** Changing the Defaults(Global) -  you change once and applicable for all

1. Go to this file `\resources\lang\en\validation.php`
2. Then change the default messages

**2.** Customizing your own preferred message (local) -  you change each in every instance you validate. Example below:

```
$this->validate($request, [  
     'id' => 'required',
     'name' => 'required'
],[
    'required' => 'Please fill empty field(s).',
    'name.required' => 'Please enter your name.'
]);
```